# react serviceworker.js relative path behind nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, routes, service-worker

So I have a domain (company.com) and this points to an nginx reverse proxy.
Nginx routes the requests to different apps (on different internal IPs) depending on the path:

company.com/login
company.com/dashboard
company.com/api

dashboard and login are frontend react apps that in turn query from the api.

Problem I am having is routing to the right app via nginx. Nginx location for each endpoint looks like

`location /login {
        proxy_pass http://login.internal.app/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }`

The service worker however due to react (using `create-react-app`) is set to `/serviceworker.js`. For static files, I think I have got that working, by setting `"homepage": "./",` in `package.json` making them relative, and then setting a base url in the HTML; `<base href="/login">`. However I don't know how to get the service worker to do the same, and I need to so that it gets routed to the correct react app on the back end.

Info

- Using docker containers, with nginx reverse proxy in front of the apps
- I need the apps on the same domain so that I dont have CORS issues
- I need the same session token to be set for the domain hence paths not subdomains

Help appreciated :)

EDIT:
With further inspection, I think what is happening is the app that sits on `/`(which is the login app - it sits on both `/` and `/login`) is catching all paths, and the service working of that app is trying to route the paths through its react `BrowserRouter`. I had understood that if the Router/serviceworker didn't have an endpoint it would pass it back to the server. If not, how do I get it to do that?